# Google docs viewer get tht total number of pages in document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-document-viewer

I am opening documents (**`pdf`**,**`docx`**,**`pptx`**) at my site using **`google docs viewer`** in an **`iframe`**. How can I get the **`total number of pages`** in the **`document`** and also how to get the **`current page number`**?